# Adding public SSH key to a git repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, copy, ssh-keys

To practice git I made the `gituser` create a `bare repository` in the directory `/home/gituser/project.git`. I later created a new user on my computer name `Tom` and I created `sshkeys` for it the ssh keys are stored in `/home/Tom/.ssh` directory.  How would I be able to add the user `Tom`'s `public ssh key` to `gituser`'s repository so that Tom can commit and push changes to the repository? Both of the users have admin permissions on ubuntu 20.04 and only the `gituser` is in a group:`dev`. Note that both the users are on the same computer.

I know that the command to copy your public keys is :

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <server>
```

but I am confused on what I can place for the `server`.

Outputs for `gituser`:

```
gituser@D-82I:~$ cd .ssh
-bash: cd: .ssh: No such file or directory
gituser@D-82I:~$ pwd
/home/gituser
gituser@D-82I:~$ ls
project.git
gituser@D-82I:~$ cd project.git/
gituser@D-82I:~/project.git$ ls
HEAD  branches  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Outputs for user `Tom` and Errors:

```
Tom@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I:~$ ls
Tom@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I:~$ pwd
/home/Tom
Tom@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I:~$ cd .ssh
Tom@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I:~/.ssh$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
Tom@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/Tom/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname /home/gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys: Name or service not known
Tom@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I:~$ git remote add origin gituser@serverName:/home/gituser/project.git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server should be:

- the remote user account gituser which created the bare repo
- the remote server hostname or IP address where the repo was created.

That means `server:~gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys` will receive Tom public SSH key.

From Tom's workstation, you can add the remote URL to your local repository:

```
git remote add origin gituser@serverName:/home/gituser/project.git
```

And push to it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I am still having trouble I have added the console outputs trying to add `Tom` to the `git` server but its still not working. Could you please take another look at it. The last 2 inputs in the Outputs for user Tom and Errors section contains the errors.

Comment: @edgeselcuk The [`ssh-copy-id`](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id#copy-the-key-to-a-server) should be `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub gituser/@servername`

Comment: Hi sorry for the long wait but I have done `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub gituser/@DESKTOP-AVNQ82I` and now it gave me the error: `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host desktop-avnq82i port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: @edgeselcuk sorry typo: It is `gituser@servername`, not `gituser/@servername`: no `/`.

Comment: Hi now it is giving me the error `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @edgeselcuk That is because you are not in a git repository, meaning a folder initialized with a `git init` command.

Comment: but when I switch over to over to the `gituser` my git rep is in the directory:`/home/gituser/project.git`. It has all the directories for a git rep `HEAD  branches  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs`.

Comment: @edgeselcuk the `git remote add origin` is to be done from the source server (in a local repository folder), not the remote target server `gituser@serverName`

Comment: oh so I just do `git init` on the user account `Tom` and then I added the `git remote origin` . I got no errors. thanks for the help. Does this mean that user `Tom's` `public ssh` keys have been added to the `gituser`'s bare repository? Or would I still have to copy the public rsa key to `gituser`'s rep. How would i be able to check for this?

Comment: @edgeselcuk "Does this mean that user Tom's public ssh keys have been added to the gituser's bare repository?": yes and no. Yes, Tom's public ssh keys have been added to the gituser's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. But no, not to the  "gituser's bare repository".

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. I also have another question is there a way to only allow certain users to be able to copy their public keys to the admin git users account? For example i allow `Tom` to upload his key but I don't allow `Jerry` to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248085/discussion-between-vonc-and-edge-selcuk).